# Input sanitization with javascript/mootools?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mootools

I have recently inherited a large website. I have been checking it for security flaws.

I have the following code, which is called when the user submits an update to their user details:

```
// Ajax request
new Request.JSON({ method: 'get', url: 'ajax.ashx', autoCancel: true, urlEncoded: false, secure: false,
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
    onSuccess: function (_json) {
        if (!_json.error) {
            $('inp_firstname').value = _json.fn;
            $('inp_surname').value = _json.sn;
            $('usr_Country').value = $(ddlCountry0).getSelected()[0].get('text');
            $('inp_companyname').value = _json.cn;
            $('inp_website').value = _json.ws;
            $('inp_facebook').value = _json.fb;
            $('inp_twitter').value = _json.tw;
            $('bus_Activity').value = $(ddlActivity0).getSelected()[0].get('text');
            $('private_contacts').value = $(chkPrivateContacts).checked;

            hidePopup('editDetailsPopup');
        }
    }
}).get({ 'm': 'editDetailsPro',
    'fn': removeTags($('firstname').value),
    'sn': removeTags($('surname').value),
    'pwd': removeTags($('password').value),
    'country': $(ddlCountry0).getSelected()[0].get('value'),
    'cn': removeTags($('companyname').value),
    'ws': removeTags($('website').value),
    'ac': $(ddlActivity0).getSelected()[0].get('value'),
    'pc': $(chkPrivateContacts).checked == 1,
    'fb': removeTags($('facebooklink').value),
    'tw': removeTags($('twitterlink').value) });
```

It turns out that the function `removeTags();` Doesn't do anything. There is also no serverside validation of input, so this is a big security hole.

What do I need to check for clientside to make sure that legitimate users can enter their data, and are there library functions that will do all these checks for me (I couldn't find any)? When it gets to the server, do I turn it back into its original form, or stick it into the database as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MooTools has the `stripTags` method, I think that's what you want: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/String.Extras#String:stripTags

Might I add though that you should **never** do JavaScript sanitization **alone**? Always do server side validation and sanitization of incoming user input. Seeing as you use ASP.NET, check this link:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should not rely on client side validation. It's nice to have, so you could alert users of incorrect data before sending it to the server, but you also need server side validation. Javascript may be disabled, or a malicious user could just send a request with harmful data to your server (without using your page, so without security checks).